# Converting script to MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've just found the following script available online but am looking for help to edit it as I know most of these functions are no longer usable and I am not sure what I would need to change and what I wouldn't for this script to work with MySQLi?

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Language, Authorization');
header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization');

# CONFIG
define('_DB_HOST', 'mysql.co.uk');
define('_DB_NAME', 'main');
define('_DB_USER', 'admin');
define('_DB_PASS', 'password');

# DB CONNECT
$connection = mysql_connect(_DB_HOST, _DB_USER, _DB_PASS) or die ('Unable to connect to MySQL server.<br ><br >Please make sure your MySQL login details are correct.');
$db = mysql_select_db(_DB_NAME, $connection) or die ('request "Unable to select database."');

# ACTION
$keys = isset($_REQUEST['keys'])?$_REQUEST['keys']:array();
if (!is_array($keys)){
    $keys = array($keys);
}
$keys = array_filter($keys);

# RESULT
$unavailable = array();
if (!empty($keys)){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') IN ('".implode("', '", $keys)."')";
    $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
        $unavailable[] = $row['date'];
    }
}
echo(json_encode($unavailable));
exit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a large scale project conversion from mysql to mysqli in the past, and it's really not very difficult. For starters, the mysqli library allows you to use both an Object Oriented style or a Procedural style, and the Procedural style very closely matches the older mysql functions.

Rather than convert all your code for you, I think it's more valuable to show you how easy it is to do yourself. The key is get used to the php docs, they are your friend!

For every mysql_* function you find in the code, look up on php.net both the mysql version and the mysqli version and compare what parameters each one expects, as well as the return types. There are many mysqli procedural style functions that simply change the order of the parameters.

For example, the first mysql_* function in your code is `mysql_connect`. Looking at [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php), this function expects to receive the host, username and password (plus some optional parameters). On that page following the link it suggests to `mysqli_connect` we see that it is an alias of `mysqli::__construct`. So clicking through to that we finally see that it also expects host, username and password. So you are good to go on this one, just add the missing "i" to the function call.

Next for `mysql_select_db`, it expects the database name and an optional link to the database connection link. For `mysqli_select_db` it expects the connection link and then the database name. Easy, just swap the order of your parameters to convert that call to mysqli. (Note that in `mysqli_connect` it takes an optional 4th parameter where you can specify the database name and skip the step of doing `mysqli_select_db` if you wish.)

Try to convert some of the other functions using the documentation, and if you run into problems please post your new code and I will try to help.